# Can you put a += operator into a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list

In python I have a list of strings that are digits. I have a nested for loop to go through it and sum each digit. Is there a way to do this in a list comprehension? Below I have the loop that works and a list comprehension that doesnt work.

num_sum should = 1 + 1 + 8 + 9

```
number_list = ["1", "18", "9"]

for i in number_list:
       for j in i:
           num_sum += int(j)

# thing = [num_sum += int(j) for i in number_list for j in i]
```

Comment: No, you can't, because that is part of a statement and not an expression, and you can only put expressions in your list comprehension

Answer (score 3):

This is what you're after, I think?

```
thing = sum(int(n) for n in number_list)
```

Note: this is effectively a generator, there's no need to put the numbers in a list and then sum them, which is why you don't see `[]` inside the parentheses of the call to `sum()`.

Or from your example it looks like you actually want to sum the individual digits:

```
thing = sum(int(d) for n in number_list for d in n)
```

To answer your question whether you can put a `+=` operator in a list comprehension - you could, but it has no return value itself for all types. `+=` assigns to the expression before the operator, but that assignment itself may or may not have a return value, which would get added to the list you're building in the comprehension. In most cases, that's not what you're after.

@ShadowRanger suggested the solution proposed by @yyforbidden may be faster - it is, in fact:

```
import random
from timeit import timeit

number_list = [str(random.randint(1, 100)) for _ in range(100)]


def comprehension():
    return sum(int(d) for n in number_list for d in n)


def joined():
    return sum(int(d) for d in ''.join(number_list))


assert comprehension() == joined()

print(timeit(comprehension, number=10000))
print(timeit(joined, number=10000))
```

Result:

```
0.4073738
0.3616424
```

I'd still prefer the comprehension because it more literally states what is going on and readable code is often preferable to performing code - but your needs may differ.

Comment: Yes pretty much! ```num_sum = sum([int(j) for i in number_list for j in i])```

Comment: Note you don't need the square brackets in there; if the answer is right for your question, please accept it, so the question no longer shows as open.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. That's a syntax error.

You can do the following instead:

```py
number_list = ["1", "18", "9"]
num_sum = sum(int(i) for i in ''.join(number_list))
```

Comment: Good observation about `join`ing the `str`s to just get a single `str` to iterate. Probably faster than even my `chain.from_iterable` solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, but in Python 3.2+ you can [use `itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to achieve a similar effect, with [`chain` to flatten your `list` of `str`s of digits to an iterable of digits](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import accumulate, chain

thing = list(accumulate(map(int, chain.from_iterable(number_list))))
num_sum = thing[-1]
```

or if you don't actually need the `list`:

```
num_sum = sum(map(int, chain.from_iterable(number_list)))
```

In 3.8+, [the walrus operator, `:=`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), makes constructing the `list` with a listcomp possible without `accumulate`, though you can't use `+=`, only explicit addition and reassignment, as `:=` doesn't have an expression based `+=` equivalent:

```
num_sum = 0
things = [(num_sum := num_sum + int(x)) for x in chain.from_iterable(number_list)]

# Chain not strictly necessary; could also do this though it would be a titch slower:
things = [(num_sum := num_sum + int(x)) for num in number_list for x in num]
```