# How can I use list comprehension to count high or low pair?

Tags: python

I am trying to make my code more elegant/less verbose with list comprehension.  I have the following so far:

```
a = [47, 67, 22]
b = [26, 47, 12]

at = 0
bt = 0
    
for a, b in [c for c in zip(a, b)]:
    if a>b:
        at+=1
    elif a<b:
        bt+=1
```

I've been trying to do something like this to remove the if elif statements:

```
[at+=1 if (a>b) else bt+=1 if (a<b) for a, b in [c for c in zip(a, b)]]
```

Which gives me a invalid syntax error highlighting the `at+=1` (so I've gone down a rabbit hole:

```
[at+=1 if (a>b) else bt+=1 if (a<b) else hello=None for a, b in [c for c in zip(a, b)]] 
       ^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: what happens if `a==b`? (i.e. your list comprehension is not equal to the "long form" above.)

Comment: if a == b then at and bt remain at 0, Python says it's the at+=1 that's the error

Comment: `[c for c in zip(a, b)]` is entirely superfluous and can be reduced to just `zip(a, b)`.

Comment: The expression in a list comprehension must return a value, not have a side effect. Think about what kind of list you could return that expresses the desired result.

Comment: You could do something like `at = sum(x > y for x, y in zip(a, b))`

Comment: Check this, probably dupe question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405812/can-you-put-a-operator-into-a-list-comprehension  . Cant use += on list compreheison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that list comprehension is more elegant (because it can be harder to read for people new to the language). However, you can write something like:

```py
a = [47, 67, 22]
b = [26, 47, 12]

at = sum(1 for x,y in zip(a,b) if x > y)
bt = sum(1 for x,y in zip(a,b) if x < y)
```

This uses a generator expression to count all the pairs which are either truly greater or truly smaller.

You are running into syntax errors because the trinary operator (`bar if foo else baz`) needs all three parts. It also *must* produce an output, so you can't use it to filter during a comprehension.

If you wish to filter during a comprehension you need to use the `(<expr> for <iterator> if <filter_expr>)` variant of a comprehension which will skip elements for which the `filter_expr` evaluates to `false`.

**Edit**: Deceze pointed out that this will iterate over the list twice. This is true and *could* be fixed by sacrificing readability:

```py
a = [47, 67, 22]
b = [26, 47, 62]  # changed the array for demo purposes

result = sum(1 if x > y else 1j if x < y else 0 for x,y in zip(a,b))
at, bt = int(result.real), int(result.imag)
```

This solution is, however, specific to this particular example.

Comment: You can simplify a bit by replacing `1 ... if x > y` with `x > y ...` (based on True having a value of 1)

Comment: @Swifty Yes, we could write it like you said. My thinking here is that OP wants to filter/branch the logic inside a list comprehension (hence the walrus operator combined with a trinary operator). The "correct" way to achieve this is to use `[... for ... if ...]`; though that doesn't change you being 100% correct in saying that this specific case can be solved by "adding 0" instead of filtering :thumbs-up:

Comment: This is about as nice as you'll get with a comprehension, but note that it'll double the runtime. Not much of a big deal for this example, but could be a problem for seriously large lists.

Comment: @deceze Yes, passing over the list twice may take more wall-clock time for long lists because data will rotate out of the cache and will have to be reloaded. Still not sure if this is what we are after here though, because this case is better solved with numpy and vectorization ... Nevertheless, this specific case can actually be solved in a single iteration using complex numbers. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Creative solution. You'd definitely want to write about as much documentation above this though as the number of lines you saved. ;)

Comment: @deceze I agree. Hence, my disclaimer that writing it like this sacrifices readability (:

Comment: Using complex numbers to parallelize the processing is a nice trick :)

Comment: I love this @FirefoxMetzger I didn't even consider complex numbers.  So clever, nice one!

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension returns exactly one value of output for every one value in the input. Obviously your desired result doesn't fit this description. What you want can be better described with a [*reduction*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce): reduce a list of values to one (or a few) results:

```
from functools import reduce

at, bt = reduce(
    lambda t, i: (t[0] + 1, t[1]) if i[0] > i[1] else (t[0], t[1] + 1) if i[0] < i[1] else t,
    zip(a, b),
    (0, 0)
)
```

Whether this is any better than what you have is debatable.

This can be further condensed to:

```
at, bt = reduce(
    lambda t, i: (t[0] + (i[0] > i[1]), t[1] + (i[0] < i[1])),
    zip(a, b),
    (0, 0)
)
```

Explanation:

`t` starts out as `(0, 0)`, `i` is a pair of numbers from `zip`.
The lambda returns a new tuple with `(0 + (i[0] < i[1]), ...)`. I.e. it adds `True` or `False` to `0`, which are treated as `1` and `0` respectively. Same for the second `0` in the tuple.
On the next iteration, `t` is the newly updated tuple (here `(1, 0)`).
In the end `reduce` returns the tuple, which will be `(3, 0)` here, and we're unpacking that to `at` and `bt`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
a = [47, 67, 22]
b = [26, 47, 12]

x, y = zip(*((x > y, x < y) for x, y in zip(a, b)))
at, bt = sum(x), sum(y)
```